# Use of undefined constant JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE'

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I recently cloned a laravel project and after running composer install, I am getting this error

```
In LogManager.php line 416:

Use of undefined constant JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE'
```

I have checked the web for solutions but can't find any related. Any assistance, please?

Also, how can I find the LogManager.php? It doesn't seem to be available when I search with VSCode

Comment: Check your PHP version - from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) - 7.2.0 JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE, and JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE options were added.

Comment: @NigelRen please help explain how to handle the error being thrown inside the Laravel application. This is specific to the php version 7.2 and related to how the Laravel log system.

Comment: did you found a solution ? facing same issue

Answer (score 17):

You should upgrade your php version to 7.2+. If that is not possible, here is a fix that i used. Just add this to your index.php file:

```
if (!defined('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE')) {
    //PHP < 7.2 Define it as 0 so it does nothing
    define('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you use higher version of php CLI you use to run `composer install` on command line, than php version on Webserver configuration (this occasionally happen).

You just need to set the webserver configuration to use the same php CLI version you use on command line.

Comment: This was my problem too. Using `php -version` in the terminal returns 7.3. But if I create a `test.php` file with `phpinfo();` then the version is still 7.1